# Working out the efficiency of my class-a audio amplifier on LTspice

Tags: ltspice, efficiency, power-amplifier

[image]

I can't seem to work it out using the tutorials on YouTube, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Homework?  Look in the LTSpice literature -- you should be able to get the power output of the voltage source, and the power dissipation of R5 (I assume that's your load).  LTSpice has a way to integrate a trace over time, so you can get averages.

Comment: Ash, you can use LTspice to report the power on every single device there (and/or the power supplied by the power supply, as well.) One of those devices is R5. The power dissipated by R5 divided by the total power of the circuit provides the value I think you want. But given it is a 1 M resistor, I can pretty much tell you that the efficiency (as I suggest measuring it) will be about zero. Only a couple of microwatts in R5, at most, my guess.

Comment: @timwescott yh it was my coursework, i was doing it right all along and because my efficiency was so low i thought i did something wrong, but it was just the circuit which was sh!t lol

Comment: You need to run the simulation for a lot longer than 1ms, especially with a 1 kHz signal. And you should replace the "NPN" transistor with a library component with realistic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In LTspice, power can be obtained by clicking on a component using *Alt+LMB* (left mouse button) (a little thermometer icon will appear when you hover over a component). You can do this for R5 and V2. For V2 power, edit the graph equation for V2's power and place a negative sign to correct the polarity, i.e., `-V(vcc)*I(V1)`.

You can integrate the graphical power traces to get power by clicking on the graphical annotation with *Ctrl+LMB*.

As @periblepsis states, the efficiency of this sort of circuit will be very poor.

[Edit]
Simulation showing waveform maths panels.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much, is there anything i can change to make the circuit more efficient without adding transformers and keep it a very basic class amplifier circuit.

Comment: @AshG This type of circuit is generally inefficient, especially with R5 being a high resistance. Not much you can do with this circuit topology to make it more efficient. And, NO, thecircuit is not "sh!t", you have unreasonable expectations of a potentially useful circuit.

Comment: @AshG Theoretical maximum for Class A with resistive load is 25%, with inductive load (replace the collector resistor with a large inductance or transformer) it's 50%. That's the best it can do in theory, real world will be worse. That's why audio power amplifiers are usually run Class B or AB unless you're willing to sacrifice inefficiency for slightly lower distortion. For a small signal voltage amplifier such as in the pre-amp stages it's fine, they don't use a lot of power anyway.

Comment: Everything about that circuit screams "efficiency doesn't matter".  Consider that the most power you'll ever see at R5 is 144 microwatts.  The bias circuit consumes about 30 times that, and the transistor's standing current consumes 3-4 times more than the bias circuit.  So it may be good to ask what that's doing in the larger scheme of things, and whether it's really impacting overall system efficiency.

Comment: @qrk Should i use the rms values to calculate the effciency or the average

Comment: @AshG RMS doesn't make sense when talking about power, Average does. When Ctrl+LMB clicking on the power graphical annotation in LTspice, the program will give you Average power and energy over the time span. It will not show an RMS value for the power traces. I added a simulation showing the panels with the average power information with a bit of Photoshop manipulation to show both panels for input and output power. I used a different resistor value for R5 than what you have in your question.